# Why are some nodes ignored by `print_model_analysis ` when `run_meta` is provided?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to compute the number of variables and the number of floating point operations of models. However, it seems that `tf.contrib.tfprof.model_analyzer.print_model_analysis` ignores the first node when  `run_meta` is provided.

For example, (test with tensorflow 1.0.0)

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
slim = tf.contrib.slim

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 7, 7, 3])
c1 = slim.conv2d(x, 22, [3, 3])

run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    _ = sess.run(c1, feed_dict={x: np.zeros([1, 7, 7, 3])},          
                 options=tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE),
                 run_metadata=run_metadata)

analysis = tf.contrib.tfprof.model_analyzer.print_model_analysis(
    tf.get_default_graph(), run_meta=run_metadata,
    tfprof_options=tf.contrib.tfprof.model_analyzer.FLOAT_OPS_OPTIONS)

# 1078
print(analysis.total_float_ops)
```

It only contains the number of floating point operations for `Conv/BiasAdd`. How can I analyze the model correctly using `tfprog`?

Comment: It seems only a op types have `RegisterStatistics` registered, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42309202/profiling-tensorflow-using-tfprof . A more comprehensive profiling is to do collect run_metadata and look at actual execution time, which is available for all ops

Comment: Thank you @YaroslavBulatov. But when I call `x.set_shape([1, 7, 7, 3])` after `x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 7, 7, 3])`, `analysis.total_float_ops` will contain ops for convolution. It seems that the shape of *input tensor* cannot be `None`, otherwise the first op will be ignored.

Comment: ah right, it uses static graph analysis to compute flops, so all the shapes must be defined